# Pardot scoring categories

Tags: pardot

Good day everyone,
At the moment I have reached the limit of the Pardot Scoring Categories.
I am going to merge multiple scoring categories into one category, but I am not sure how it will affect all existing prospects and leads, will they keep their scoring history, also scoring categories are used for creating Lead Tasks.
What can be the options how to reduce the number of scoring categories but save the history of scoring points for prospects and leads?
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!